# Play Google TTS in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, text-to-speech

I am doing an app for Windows 8 in C#. In that app I have a Text to speech part. I am currently using bing translator api but I have found Google TTS api is much efficient. I was using this code

```
<MediaElement x:Name="medEle" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"  Height="100" Width="100"/>

private void speakword(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   prgrsRing_Copy.IsActive = true;

   string path = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Windows";
   medEle.Source = new Uri(path,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
   medEle.Play();
  prgrsRing_Copy.IsActive = false;
}
```

But this is not working. Please help me to do this.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to source directly to an http address. The URI is really meant for local Resource URIs. What this means is, you'll likely have to download the mp3 from that location, save it to the Apps local storage, then access it from there. Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781239.aspx) to get started with downloading the mp3.

Comment: Since I am new to windows 8 development, can you please post any sample code

Comment: Your code should work. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Text-to-speech-in-Windows-93e6ded3#content this sample contains same thing as your problem